# How to share Google Pay payment link through Whatsapp from Laravel website

Tags: javascript, laravel, google-pay

I am trying to share the UPI link mentioned below, to the customer through WhatsApp.

`https://tez.google.com/pay/?pa=***&pn=***&tr=123&url=***&mc=123&tn=Purchas`e

But I can only open the first interface through this link and unable to fetch the parameter values. I have googled the same and can see the below link from it,

```
upi://pay?pa=***&pn=***&tr=123&am=1&cu=INR)
```

But the above link is not in the clickable format.

I am working on Laravel.

If this is not a good practice to share GPay payment link through WhatsApp, can you please suggest a workaround?

It will be more helpful if you could help me to solve this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: I am looking for the same to share on whatsapp to pay to gpay mobile no. like https://tez.google.com/pay/?mobile=+911234567890 . Do anyone have the idea to do so

Comment: I am looking for the same. Can you please help me with the same or possible work arounds please